# Trying to place shortcode/css/html into an IF conditional statement

Tags: conditional-tags, plugins

With the WooCommerce plugin, I'm trying to get a different template/look to apply to the individual product page depending on what category the product is in. In other words, I want a product within the "A" category to have one look, and another product within the "Z" category to have another separate look. I realize there are similar questions asked, and I have used them to try and attempt this myself, but I'm having no luck getting them to work, so I would like to try something different:
I need to place the following code:

http://pastebin.com/q18EJYZQ

Inside this IF statement: http://pastebin.com/WkhkEemH

Or some kind of similar conditional.  So if the product has a category of "z", then echo out the html, css, and shortcode shown in the first pastebin link. If the product is not part of the "z" category then no extra html/css/shortcode is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting all terms, looping over them and then searching your array, you can use the `has_term`conditinal tag ex:

```
if( has_term( 'z', 'product_cat',$post->ID ) ) {
    ?>
    <div id="post-timer">
        <p class="timebuy">Time Left To Buy:</p>
        <div id="timer-wrap">
            <?php echo do_shortcode( '[tminus cid ="12" omitweeks="true" days=" " hours=" " minutes=" " seconds=" "/]' ); ?>
        </div><!--end timer-wrap-->
    </div><!--end post-timer-->
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Fantastic sir! Works like a charm. Thank you very much!